# PostgreSQL: проблема с вытаскиванием данных из JSON

Tags: postgresql

Есть у меня такой string, претендующий на JSON:

```
[{"desc": "select your age group", "name": "age", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["age 15-30", "age 31-45", "age 46-60"]}]
```

Мне нужно сделать что-то типа

```
WITH all_values AS (
    SELECT projectid AS projectid,
           prompttype AS prompttype,
           el.inputs->>'name' AS name,
           el.inputs->>'desc' AS description,
           v.value AS value,
           scriptid AS scriptid,
           corpuscode AS corpuscode
    FROM source.table
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(inputs::jsonb) AS el(inputs)
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(el.inputs->'values') AS v(value)
    WHERE
        prompttype = 'input' AND (created > getdate() - interval '30 minutes' OR modified > getdate() - interval '30 minutes')
    GROUP BY projectid, prompttype, name, description, scriptid, corpuscode, v.value
   )
```

В общем случае в PostgreSQL это работает нормально. Но когда пробую применять в RedShift, то ошибка возле inputs::jsonb - он не знает, что такое ::, у него нет типа данных json и jsonb. Приходится думать обходные варианты как достать значения из JSON.

Начал тестировать с малого:

```
WITH all_values AS (
        SELECT json_extract_path_text(inputs, 'desc', TRUE)
        FROM source.table)
SELECT * FROM all_values;
```

но тут он выводит пустоту.

Попробовал преобразовать inputs - убрать из него лишние скобки.

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(inputs,'[{','{'), '}]','}'), '"', '\'') FROM source.table WHERE prompttype ='input' ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 40;
```

Сейчас строка выглядит так:

```
{'desc': 'select your age group', 'name': 'age', 'type': 'dropdown', 'values': ['age 15-30', 'age 31-45', 'age 46-60']}
```

Но когда снова пытаюсь запустить

```
WITH all_values AS (
        SELECT json_extract_path_text(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(inputs,'[{','{'), '}]','}'), '"', '\''), 'desc', TRUE)
        FROM source.table)
SELECT * FROM all_values;
```

то он выводит пустоту снова...

Не могу зацепиться как вытащить значения из строки в RedShift.

Comment: не нужно постоянно дублировать вопросы и ответы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача решается так:

```
SELECT json_extract_array_element_text(inputs, 0, True) FROM source.table WHERE prompttype = 'input' LIMIT 10;
                           
SELECT json_extract_path_text(json_extract_array_element_text(inputs, 0, True), 'desc') FROM source.table WHERE prompttype = 'input' LIMIT 10;
```

Параметр True означает, что запрос не будет парсить те строки, в которых содержится не корректный JSON.